# Directly link to app rating page in app store

Tags: swift, app-store

I would like to ask, is it possible to link directly to the rating page in app store?

I have a button where the user can click on the rate icon and he will be redirected to the app in the app store.

My code at the moment looks like so:

```
@IBAction func rateClicked(sender: AnyObject) {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string : "itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/id0000000000")!)
}
```

I would like if possible to redirect directly to the rating screen insead to the app. 
I mean on this screen:

[Image](http://s23.postimg.org/hn9m30i5n/rating.jpg)

Thanks

Comment: Appirater does exactly that. It is open source, check it out: https://github.com/arashpayan/appirater

Comment: Looks like Appirater no more works for the new iOS version. At least not on iOS 9.3.2.